# vaadin 7 websockets

Tags: websocket, vaadin

I am newbie to vaadin. I have few questions:

1. Does Vaadin 7 or later version supports websockets?
2. Does Vaadin has any other features like pushing data from server to client (e.g. websockets)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vaadin support [Atmosphere](http://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere), so google to get the plugin that will enable websockets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.Does it support All the web browser

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Supported-WebServers-and-Browsers

Answer (score 2):

Server push is the main feature coming with Vaadin 7.1 in a few weeks time. See the [Roadmap](https://vaadin.com/roadmap) for current status and the related [blog post](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/roadmap-for-the-next-74-days).

The most downloaded add-on for server push before Vaadin 7.1 is [ICEPush](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/icepush%3avaadin) but you can find other alternatives in the [add-on directory](https://vaadin.com/directory#browse%3avaadin,search=push) as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Update - *Push* Is Built-In

Both of the other answers by [jfarcand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044473/jfarcand) (creator of [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere)) and [Ludd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864133/ludd) were correct, but are now outdated.

Vaadin 7.3.7 (as of 2015-01) now incorporates the [Atmosphere library](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). Atmosphere provides for built-in support of [Push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). No need to add any jar, library, plugin, nor add-on. Vaadin Push first tries to use WebSocket technology. If not available, Vaadin Push falls back to other approaches.

Three simple steps:

1. Add the [`@Push`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.4.0/com/vaadin/annotations/Push.html) annotation to your UI subclass
2. Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to update data for your app in the background. Probably best to start and stop the executor service in a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), called as your Vaadin web app launches and shuts down.
3. When fresh data is ready, the background thread calls the [UI::access](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#access(java.lang.Runnable)) method to schedule access to, and make changes to, the user interface components (widgets) on the UI thread (the Request-handling thread).

Instead of Step # 2, you might want one user’s main user-interface thread to update another user’s display. Basically the same idea, and covered in the Book Of Vaadin.

## Book Of Vaadin

See [section 11.16](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html) in [The Book Of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book) for more info about Server Push.

## Minimal Example

In 2015-01, I posted [this answer for a minimal example of Push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27808461/642706) in Vaadin 7. You can copy the content of a single file, to replace your the content of the `MyUI` class in a new default Vaadin project.