# Minimal example of Push in Vaadin 7 app ("@Push")

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, web-push

I want to see the most minimal example of using the new [Push technology](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html) in Vaadin 7, such as the new `@Push` annotation.

I am having problems getting [server-push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) to work in my app. I would like to try a simple example app before trying to fix my own app.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: After studying this page, you may find this page useful: [Displaying Same Data Aross Multiple Clients Using Push in Vaadin 7 app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27872756/642706)

Comment: For a full working example of asynchronously updating a widget in the UI using Push in Vaadin 8, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885540/642706) on the Question, [*Vaadin: Update UI after data returned*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50880506/642706)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Simplification Of Example In *The Book Of Vaadin*

The [Book Of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book) includes a chapter on Push, including an example using [Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts).

Below is my code. While based on that Vaadin Charts example mentioned above, I simplified it by replacing the use of a [`Chart`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/Chart.html) object with a simple [`Label`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Label.html) object. The Label updates every second or so to tell you the current time.

[image: screen shot of example Vaadin app telling current time in UTC as text]

## For Example Use Only – Use an Executor in real-world project

**Caveat:** My example below is built for simplicity, ***not intended as production code***. Sleeping a thread is a crude and awkward way to manage scheduled threaded work. Java provides the `Executor` facility for this kind of work. In a real-world project I would use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) rather than a single sleeping [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) object to schedule our task (of telling time). Related tip: Never use a `Timer` in a Servlet environment. For a fuller and more real-world example, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872769/642706) to a similar Question about Push with Vaadin.

I took other shortcuts in this example, such as: I place the `Label` widget directly on the `UI` whereas real-world work would use a `Layout` to contain the `Label`.

## My Configuration

My code is using Vaadin 7.3.7 with Java 8 Update 25 in NetBeans 8.0.2 and Tomcat 8.0.15 on Mac OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion).

Push technology is relatively new, especially the [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) variety. Be sure to use recent versions of your web server, such as recent updates to Tomcat 7 or 8.

## How To Use This Example

This code is a single file, the `MyUI.java` file. To use this code:

1. Create a new default Vaadin app in your IDE of choice.
2. Get that example running successfully, before modifying.
3. Replace the contents of `MyUI` class with the code below.

## `@Push` Annotation

Beside the code in the middle, note how we added the [`@Push`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/Push.html) annotation to the `MyUI` class definition.

## Example Code

```
package com.example.pushvaadinapp;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Push;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Widgetset;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

/**
 * © 2014 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone absolving me of any and all responsibility.
 *
 *  +----------------------------+
 *  |  NOT FOR PRODUCTION USE!   |
 *  +----------------------------+
 *     Sleeping threads is an awkward way to manage scheduled background work.
 *     By the way, never use a 'Timer' in a Servlet environment. 
 *     Use an Executor instead, probably a ScheduledExecutorService.
 */
@Push
@Theme ( "mytheme" )
@Widgetset ( "com.example.pushvaadinapp.MyAppWidgetset" )
public class MyUI extends UI
{

    Label label = new Label( "Now : " );

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest vaadinRequest )
    {
        // Put a widget on this UI. In real work we would use a Layout.
        setContent( this.label );

        // Start the data feed thread
        new FeederThread().start();
    }

    @WebServlet ( urlPatterns = "/*" , name = "MyUIServlet" , asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( ui = MyUI.class , productionMode = false )
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet
    {
    }

    public void tellTime ()
    {
        label.setValue( "Now : " + new java.util.Date() ); // If Java 8, use: Instant.now(). Or, in Joda-Time: DateTime.now().
    }

    class FeederThread extends Thread
    {

        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            try {
                // Update the data for a while
                while ( count < 100 ) {
                    Thread.sleep( 1000 );

                    // Calling special 'access' method on UI object, for inter-thread communication.
                    access( new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run ()
                        {
                            count ++;
                            tellTime();
                        }
                    } );
                }

                // Inform that we have stopped running
                // Calling special 'access' method on UI object, for inter-thread communication.
                access( new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run ()
                    {
                        label.setValue( "Done." );
                    }
                } );
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the widgetset needed?  my guess: no.  also why bother with (and explain for a whole paragraph) java.time, when the goal is to have a minimal working example?  just use a counter or `new Date().toString()`.  and in your question you state, that you wanted to have a simple test app where you can test this stuff.  so why not put your **whole project** (including your pom/gradle/younameit) on github for the SO users, that find your question?

Comment: @cfrick All good points; Thank you. [A] I killed the java.time use and discussion as you suggested. [B] As for the widgetset, that annotation is the default in the new multi-module project created by [the new Maven archetype](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-7-3-7-and-new-maven-archetypes), as delivered by the 1.1.3 update to the [Vaadin Plugin For NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/vaadin-plug-in-for-netbeans). Furthermore, the vague doc implies the widgetset (and theme) is now automatically optimized in the `production` module’s compilation. So I'll leave that in place.

Comment: Why can't you use a Timer in a Servlet environment?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/mrts/vaadin-javaee-jms-server-push-example) is a simple but full Vaadin 8 example that demonstrates how to use server push and Java EE messaging APIs to send messages between different UIs using the [*Broadcaster* pattern](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/documentation/advanced/advanced-push.asciidoc#the-broadcaster) described in [Vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html). If you are not interested in messaging or broadcasting to other users, then look at [ReceiveMessageUI](https://github.com/mrts/vaadin-javaee-jms-server-push-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/serverpushexample/ReceiveMessageUI.java) only.

In principle it all boils down to the following:

1. Annotate the Vaadin UI with `@Push` to enable server push (by default over a WebSocket connection)
2. Wrap UI updates with `access()` when accessing it from other threads, sending updates happens automatically by default:

   ```
   getUI().access(() -> layout.addComponent(new Label("Hello!")));
   ```
3. Use the [*Broadcaster* pattern](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/documentation/advanced/advanced-push.asciidoc#the-broadcaster) to publish messages to other users and to subscribe to their messages.

Comment: By “Broadcaster pattern” do you mean the [*Observer* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or something else?

Comment: Something else, I mean the [Broadcaster pattern](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/documentation/advanced/advanced-push.asciidoc#the-broadcaster) documented in Vaadin docs.

Comment: Better to look for exa,ple in docs https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html